# Search in HTML for multiple strings with JS

Tags: javascript

I want to achieve the already working "if-solution-result" of this:

```
window.onload = function(){

if(document.body.innerHTML.toString().indexOf('jeff') > -1){
     alert('marker1 gefunden');
}
if(document.body.innerHTML.toString().indexOf('lisa') > -1){
     alert('marker2 gefunden');
}
// it could go on and on from here...
};
```

in a more elegant way with a "for..." loop, but i didn't get it working.

```
var marker = ["paul", "maria", "jeff", "lisa"];
for (var i=0; i<marker.length; i++){
if(document.body.innerHTML(marker) > -1){
  alert((marker) + 'gefunden');
    }
}
```

I'm stuck on the basics on how to manage information inside of loops.

What this should do in the end (as my "if" coding shows):

Load HTML >> Check if one or more of the Arrays are found >> Open an alertbox with what is found.

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML.indexOf(marker[i])`, btw, you don't need `toString()` because the attribute `innerHTML` returns a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to use the iterator in the for loop. And indexOf.

When you use a for loop like this one you have `i` thats the iterator to see at which index your are. Then you can use `i` to select the correct value from your array with `marker[i]`.

Example:

```
var marker = ["paul", "maria", "jeff", "lisa"];
for (var i=0; i<marker.length; i++){
if(document.body.innerHTML.indexOf(marker[i]) > -1){ // <-- right there
  alert((marker[i]) + 'gefunden');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two issues here,

- Use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` since `innerHTML` will also check for attribute values, etc
- Use `forEach` to iterate array and `includes` or `indexOf` to check if the value is in `body`,

for example

```
var bodyText = document.body.textContent; //save the textContent in a value beforehand rather than doing it in a loop.
var marker = ["paul", "maria", "jeff", "lisa"];
marker.forEach( (s, i) => bodyText.includes(s) && alert('marker' + i + ' gefunden') );
```

If your browser doesn't support *arrow functions* or `includes`, then

```
marker.forEach( function(s, i) { //s is the item in iteration from the array and i is the index
   //check if the body has the text and && will make sure that second expression will get executed only if first one has succeeded
   bodyText.indexOf(s) != -1 && alert('marker' + i + ' gefunden');
});
```

Comment: Making a fancy one-liner isn't gonna help a beginner ;)

Comment: @Skwal Its not that fancy :), but if OP has a problem understanding the same I can elaborate more.

Answer (score 0):

As best practice, I recommend:

1, No var, no for loop, no double quote, play with arrow function

2, You should assign `document.body.innerHTML` to a variable first:

```
let html = document.body.innerHTML;
```

(Note that you may need to strip HTML tags for better result).

3, Check every item in `marker`

```
let marker = ['paul', 'maria', 'jeff', 'lisa'];

marker.filter((keyword) => {
  return html.indexOf(keyword) > -1;
}).forEach((keyword) => {
  alert(keyword);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you explain why this is "better"? Or is this just "different"?

Comment: @maschroom yes, it is the evolution of javascript, along with the influence of functional programming. 
Assigning `document.body.innerHTML` (or anything 2 levels up) to a variable asap is the rule of clean code. That also helps you improve performance. It no longer need to find the `body` property from `document` object, then find `innerHTML` from `body`, etc.
I don't like to repeat the same story. You can google "javascript best practices" or simple setup the linter to get better recommendation.